# react-native-swipe-list-view hidden Item

Tags: typescript, react-native, mobile

I want to animated the hiddenItem like this example (see the HiddenItemAction)
https://github.com/jemise111/react-native-swipe-list-view/blob/master/SwipeListExample/examples/actions.js

But as i see, the swipedAnimatedValue (_translates  is now disappear from renderHiddenIte m and it's DEPRECATED) instead it's in renderHiddenRow.

When i use renderHiddenRow, i think i have to use renderRow (if i use renderItem, it can't be swipe). But the renderItem is required. So how can I fix this? I need the swipedValueChange for each row

Environment

- RNSLV Version: 3.2.9
- RN Version: 0.73.6